# Fedora currently missing the latest version of git

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management

So, I'm currently running Fedora 27, although this problem has been present since F26. The issue is that I'm unable to update git via normal repos. I'm confused as to why, as I can't find anything else on the 
internet about it.

My current version of Git is `2.14.3`, and it should be `2.15.1`

The contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d` is as follows

```
total 60
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  342 Oct  8 15:25 _copr_davidva-deadbeef.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  322 Sep 27 18:56 _copr_numix-numix.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  707 Oct 25 06:41 fedora-cisco-openh264.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1331 Oct 25 06:41 fedora.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1345 Oct 25 06:41 fedora-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1403 Oct 25 06:41 fedora-updates-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  258 Nov 16 20:24 hardware:razer.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1248 Nov 14 07:17 rpmfusion-free.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1245 Nov 14 07:17 rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1305 Nov 14 07:17 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1293 Nov 14 07:21 rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1290 Nov 14 07:21 rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1350 Nov 14 07:21 rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  148 Nov 27 12:38 skype-stable.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  207 Oct  9 03:14 slack.repo
```

Here's all the relevant info I thought might be useful.

#### `sudo dnf info git`

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'davidva-deadbeef', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'numix-numix', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:49:40 ago on Tue 05 Dec 2017 18:46:43 NZDT.
Installed Packages
Name         : git
Version      : 2.14.3
Release      : 2.fc27
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 2.5 M
Source       : git-2.14.3-2.fc27.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Fast Version Control System
URL          : https://git-scm.com/
License      : GPLv2
Description  : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
             : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
             : and full access to internals.
             : 
             : The git rpm installs common set of tools which are usually using with
             : small amount of dependencies. To install all git packages, including
             : tools for integrating with other SCMs, install the git-all meta-package.
```

#### `sudo dnf install git` (with git already installed)

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'davidva-deadbeef', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'numix-numix', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:53:42 ago on Tue 05 Dec 2017 18:46:43 NZDT.
Package git-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

#### `sudo dnf install git` (after uninstalling git)

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'davidva-deadbeef', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'numix-numix', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:55:24 ago on Tue 05 Dec 2017 18:46:43 NZDT.
Dependencies resolved.
===========================================================
 Package       Arch    Version              Repository
                                                      Size
===========================================================
Installing:
 git           x86_64  2.14.3-2.fc27        updates  1.1 M
Installing dependencies:
 git-core-doc  x86_64  2.14.3-2.fc27        updates  2.3 M
 perl-Error    noarch  1:0.17025-1.fc27     fedora    44 k
 perl-Git      noarch  2.14.3-2.fc27        updates   68 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================
Install  4 Packages

Total download size: 3.5 M
Installed size: 14 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/4): perl-Git-2.14.3-2.f 512 kB/s |  68 kB     00:00    
(2/4): perl-Error-0.17025- 692 kB/s |  44 kB     00:00    
(3/4): git-2.14.3-2.fc27.x 2.6 MB/s | 1.1 MB     00:00    
(4/4): git-core-doc-2.14.3 3.2 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00    
-----------------------------------------------------------
Total                      1.1 MB/s | 3.5 MB     00:03     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                   1/1 
  Installing       : perl-Error-1:0.17025-1.fc27.noa   1/4 
  Installing       : git-core-doc-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_   2/4 
  Installing       : perl-Git-2.14.3-2.fc27.noarch     3/4 
  Installing       : git-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_64          4/4 
  Running scriptlet: git-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_64          4/4 
  Verifying        : git-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_64          1/4 
  Verifying        : git-core-doc-2.14.3-2.fc27.x86_   2/4 
  Verifying        : perl-Git-2.14.3-2.fc27.noarch     3/4 
  Verifying        : perl-Error-1:0.17025-1.fc27.noa   4/4 

Installed:
  git.x86_64 2.14.3-2.fc27                                 
  git-core-doc.x86_64 2.14.3-2.fc27                        
  perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17025-1.fc27                       
  perl-Git.noarch 2.14.3-2.fc27                            

Complete!
```

It should be noted that the COPR repos have been nonfunctional since F27, but were functioning when the issue first occured.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be seen on [Bodhi](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=git), the latest version of `git` available for Fedora 27 *is* 2.14.3; the behaviour you’re seeing is perfectly normal. If you want a newer version of `git`, you’ll have to build it yourself or install it from somewhere else. You could also file a bug asking for a newer release, if that hasn’t been done already. (2.15.1 is [available for Fedora 28](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/git/builds/).)